# Find $\underset{x \to 2} \lim \frac{-4x+8}{|x-2|}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to Find $\underset{x \to 2} \lim \frac{-4x+8}{|x-2|}$, but I'm not sure how to handle the absolute value in the denominator. If I can just multiply by $\frac{|x + 2|}{|x+2|}$, are there any special rules for that? How can I handle this?

I have tried:

$$\underset{x \to 2} \lim \frac{-4x+8}{|x-2|}$$

$$=\underset{x \to 2} \lim \frac{(-4x+8)(8+4x)}{|x-2|(8+4x)}$$

$$=\underset{x \to 2} \lim \frac{64-16x^2}{|x-2|(8+4x)}$$

But it's apparent I need to change $|x - 2|$ in some way, or I will always have a zero in the denominator.

I have also tried L'Hospital's Rule.

$$\underset{x \to 2} \lim \frac{-4x+8}{|x-2|}$$

$$=\underset{x \to 2} \lim \frac{\frac{d}{dx}-4x+8}{\frac{d}{dx}|x-2|}$$

but I learned $\frac{d}{dx}|x-2|=\frac{x-2}{|x-2|}$, which doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What is the value when $x>2$?  when $x<2$ ?

Comment: try to compute $\lim_{x\to 2^+}$ and $\lim_{x\to 2^-}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to2}\frac{-4x+8}{|x-2|}&=&\lim_{x\to2}(-4)\cdot\frac{x-2}{|x-2|}\\\
&=&\lim_{x\to2}(-4)\text{sgn}(x-2)\\
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore

$$ \lim_{x\to2^+}(-4)\text{sgn}(x-2)=-4 $$

and

$$ \lim_{x\to2^-}(-4)\text{sgn}(x-2)=4 $$

So the limit does not exist at $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $$x\to 2^+\implies |x-2|=x-2$$  and if
$$x\to 2^-\implies |x-2|=-(x-2)$$